# My application proxy msi contains also dll's and therefore cannot be installed on Windows7. What can I do?

Tags: windows-7, vb6, components, windows-installer, com+

I have an VB6 application with a lot of COM+ Components. After installing them on my server, I created an application proxy MSI, to deploy it on a couple of workstations.

The installation of the proxy works fine on XP systems but not on Win7. The msi log says "Error registering COM+ application". I have also noticed, that the msi contains not only the .tlb files but also the .dll files, which should not be part of the installer. Another system for production purposes is able to create the msi without having the dll's included and this msi can also be installed on Win7 systems. (I don't have the possibility to examine these two systems for differences, since the production server is not available for me :/ )

It seems to me, that Win7 is not able to install the application proxy due to the fact that the dll's are inside the msi and the question is: What do I need to do, to let the msi be created without dll's ? Can I configure it? Have I installed the components wrong? (I used regasm and regsvcs, dll's and tlb's are within the same directory)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This might help answer the question or simply serve as a request for more info.

My suggestion would be to read through these two articles:

[How To Create a COM+ Application Proxy That Installs Only Type Library Files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/292184)

[Deploying Application Proxies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679498%28VS.85%29.aspx)

If you are already doing as suggested there, then we have a starting point from which to try helping further.

Also, what OS is on your COM+ server machine?

Comment: I already know these articles :) The first article describes how to create the components manually. Actually I have a script which first runs regasm to create the tlb's and then regsvcs to register the dll's. As far as I understand that should do exactly whats needed and also what happens as if I was doing it manually. Therefore both of the articles don't help :/

Comment: As far I can know regasm is only for creating the managed code COM wrapper registry entries (and optionally a .TLB or .REG file) for a managed code DLL.  Regsvcs is also for .Net code.  Neither creates .MSI files.  You need to use the GUI tool or write a command line utility, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680546(VS.85).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680628(VS.85).aspx

Comment: I am using regasm and regsvcs to install the components on the production server (and by the way my VB6 app is a hybrid app containing also .NET). After installing them I use the component services administration tool to create the msi. Oh and I forgot to say which OS is used: Windows Server 2003 R2